# PHP DateTime format not working properly

Tags: php

I use this code:

```
$today_date = new DateTime('now');
$final_date = new DateTime('2012-03-22 09:00');
$interval = $today_date->diff($final_date);

$time_left = $interval->format('%d:%H:%i:%s');
```

I want `$time_left` to have the format `dd:hh:mm:ss` format (d-> day, h-> hour, m-> minute, s-> seconds).

But when i used `%d:%H:%i:%s` as format, it sometimes displays single number, that is without 0 padding for minute. For example: `11:14:7:45`. Expected result: `11:14:07:45`

Any mistakes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More a comment: Don't confuse the [`format` of `DateInterval`](http://php.net/DateInterval.format) with `format` of `DateTime`: `i` is Minutes, numeric, e.g. 1, 3, 59. In case you run into a problem or you use a function you don't know in and out, please consult the manual first.

Comment: Thanku. Yes i was using like that you said. Why they didnot used same format? One is opposite of another !

Answer (score 1):

Per [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php), `%i` is "Minutes, numeric: 1, 3, 59". Try `%I` which uses leading zeroes.

Comment: Thanku. It is working. I used http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php as reference ! that is my mistake.